# ValueError: The specified interaction extension is broader than the ones already present for the given nodes

Tags: networkx, data-mining

I am working on dynamic graph with dynetx, but I am getting this error every time when try to load snapshots from the file, how to solve this error? below is the code I m writting

```
g = dn.read_snapshots('times2.txt', nodetype=int, timestamptype=int)
```

datasets example

```
469 2153 10
469 2153 5
469 2153 5
469 2153 5
469 2153 5
469 2153 5
469 2153 5
469 2153 6
469 2153 6
469 2154 10
469 2154 7
469 2155 10
469 2155 7
469 2156 10
469 2156 7
469 2157 10
469 2157 7
469 2158 10
Thank you
```

error

```
valueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-365-4dbae894b502> in <module>
----> 1 g = dn.read_snapshots('times2.txt', nodetype=int, timestamptype=int)

<C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-888> in read_snapshots(path, comments, directed, delimiter, nodetype, timestamptype, encoding, keys)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dynetx\utils\decorators.py in _open_file(func, *args, **kwargs)
    192         # Finally, we call the original function, making sure to close the fobj.
    193         try:
--> 194             result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
    195         finally:
    196             if close_fobj:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dynetx\readwrite\edgelist.py in read_snapshots(path, comments, directed, delimiter, nodetype, timestamptype, encoding, keys)
    255 
    256     return parse_snapshots(lines, comments=comments, directed=directed, delimiter=delimiter,  nodetype=nodetype,
--> 257                            timestamptype=timestamptype, keys=ids)
    258 
    259 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dynetx\readwrite\edgelist.py in parse_snapshots(lines, comments, directed, delimiter, nodetype, timestamptype, keys)
    230             if e is not None:
    231                 e = keys[e]
--> 232         G.add_interaction(u, v, t=t, e=e)
    233     return G
    234 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dynetx\classes\dyngraph.py in add_interaction(self, u, v, t, e)
    374             else:
    375                 if t[0] < app[-1][0]:
--> 376                     raise ValueError("The specified interaction extension is broader than "
    377                                      "the ones already present for the given nodes.")
    378 

ValueError: The specified interaction extension is broader than the ones already present for the given nodes.
```

Comment: Could you give use some sample data from your "times2.txt"? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - and add the python tag

Comment: Those aare datassets examples, edges and timestamps @Sparky05

Comment: Could you add the full error trace? Because I don't see any `ValueErrors` inside the code (https://github.com/GiulioRossetti/dynetx/blob/master/dynetx/readwrite/edgelist.py)

Comment: ok @Sparky05, when i read full file with these edges and timestamp that is the error

Comment: ok @Sparky05, that is the error

Answer (score 4):

With the info's you supplied, I could reconstruct the error and narrowed it down to the following:

Your observations are not ordered by time and you have multiple observations for some of the nodes (in `dynetx` this creates additional data, see below). To solve your problem you need to sort your data first by time (and may delete duplicate lines).

A small example to create your error:

```py
from dynetx import DynGraph()

dyngraph = DynGraph()

# works
snapshots = [
    [469, 2153, 5],
    [469, 2153, 5],
    [469, 2153, 10],
]

# does not work
#snapshots = [
#    [469, 2153, 10],
#    [469, 2153, 5],
#]

for u, v, t in snapshots:
    dyngraph.add_interaction(u, v, t)

    print(dyngraph.edges(data=True))
# [(469, 2153, {'t': [[5, 5]]})]
# [(469, 2153, {'t': [[5, 5], [5, 5]]})] -> is this really wanted by you?
# [(469, 2153, {'t': [[5, 5], [5, 5], [10, 10]]})]
```